# After some time MySql server goes off and I have to restart the server again and again

Tags: java, mysql, gwt

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   The last packet successfully received from the server was 38,160,127
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   38,160,127 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured
>   value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or
>   testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing
>   the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the
>   Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this
>   problem.

1) As per the solutions given by TOMCAT I have increased the value of `wait_timeout` but, it is not working.

2) How to set `autoReconnect=true` in my URL I don't know. I tried with all the possibilities but it does not work.

URL:

```
<property
    name="url"
    value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.01:3306/PaxWeb3?zeroDateTimeBehavior" />
```

I have tried using:

```
value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.01:3306/PaxWeb3?zeroDateTimeBehavior&autoReconnect=true"
```

and

```
value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.01:3306/PaxWeb3?zeroDateTimeBehavior;&amp;autoReconnect=true"
```

but they won't work either.

Comment: How much RAM is available in your machine (or virtual machine)?  You should know that 512mb (AWS micro instance) isn't enough to run both a web server and MySQL unless you're very skillful at tuning your system. Disappointing but true.

Comment: @OllieJones this has absolutely nothing to do with the error message.

Comment: You should configure connection pooling, for instance using DBCP or C3PO. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0?rq=1

Comment: I am running the code with 4GB RAM. @OllieJones