# Apache DBCP 2.1 to work with Oracle v11.2.0.1

Tags: oracle, maven, tomcat, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

we are planning to use Apache DBCP 2.1 for our connection pooling, We currently have following technology stack
Tomcat 8
Jre 7
Oracle DB 11.2.0.1

As per the Apache DBCP home page the DBCP v2.1 only works with jre7 and it requires JDBC 4.1 drivers.

I am finding very hard to get the JDBC 4.1 drivers for Oracle DB. Also I am not sure if the Oracle 11.2.0.1 even supports JDBC 4.1 drivers.

I did a lot of research on google but was not able to find link or maven dependency to use JDBC 4.1 version.

Following is where I stumbled upon

Can I use Apache DBCP 2.1 with Oracle 11.2.0.1 in Tomcat 8
Where I can find Maven dependency for JDBC 4.1 drivers for Oracle DB

Note: I do not want to use tomcat DBCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

([JDBC 4.1 is part of JDK 1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_41.html))

I checked few versions of [Oracle JDBC/ODBC drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html), but haven't find any sign of JDK 1.7 nor JDBC 4.1 compliance. So I assume it is not.

Can't you use different connection pool. We are working with c3p0 and I've seen it to be solid, if you tune it well.

**Response to comment**:

[According table @Tunaki](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03) provided and [Apache Commons DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/download_dbcp.cgi) site, yes your matrix is:

- ODBC 11.2.0.4 (JDBC 4.0 compliant)
- Apache DBCP 1.4 (JDBC 4.0 compliant)
- JDK 1.7

**EDIT2:**
Do you know that Apache DBCP is not consired as production ready by various sources:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Introduction

[Connection pooling options with JDBC: DBCP vs C3P0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0)

Why do you have such crazy requirement?

Comment: Can I use Apache DBCP 1.4 with Jre 6

Comment: Thanks, last quick think so I have downloaded Apache DBCP 1.4 in Tomcat 8 lib and it also contains tomcat-dbcp, and when I run the code it uses tomcat dbcp and not apache commons dbcp, any idea how to force it

Comment: thanks for the update, its all about Enterprise rules :)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 11g does not support JDBC 4.1. [Only Oracle 12c does](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#000_00).

See [this table](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03) on Oracle site that describes with versions of Java and JDBC is supported in which Oracle Database version.